# Month localization in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, localization, thymeleaf

I am writing a spring boot application using Thymeleaf as template engine.

Need to localize month translation of displayed date into Ukrainian:

Expected result
10-квітня-2021 18:58:53 is displayed after switching the language

In general localization (EN/UA) works fine.

I tried the following tips, but dates are still displayed in English after switching the language (i.e. 10-April-2021 18:58:53):

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped ">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                  ...
        
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
        
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each="tempReport : ${page}">
                    
                   ...
        
                    <td th:text="${#temporals.format(T(java.time.LocalDate).of(#dates.year(tempReport.reportDate),
        #dates.month(tempReport.reportDate), #dates.day(tempReport.reportDate)), 'dd-MMMM-yyyy', new java.util.Locale('ua', 'UA'))}"></td>
        
                </tr>
                </tbody>
    </table>
```

and this

```
 ...
<td th:text="${T(org.thymeleaf.util.DateUtils).monthName(#dates.createNow(), #locale)}"></td>
    ...
```

Also tried this code, and it works

```
...
        <td th:text="${T(org.thymeleaf.util.DateUtils).monthName(#dates.createNow(), #locale.GERMAN)}"></td>
...
```

but the problem is there is NO UKRAINIAN constant for this approach, like #locale.UKRAINIAN

My date in POJO class:

```
@Column(name = "report_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    @NotNull
    private Date reportDate;
```

Any help to resolve the issue will be appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you do `<td th:text="${#dates.format(tempReport.reportDate, 'dd-MMMM-yyyy')}"></td>` ?

Comment: I am not using Spring, so I do not know if this will work: When you use `#locale.GERMAN` that is just a convenient [constant value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) for one of the more commonly used languages. You can build a locale for any language using the relevant language tag. So, try `#locale.forLanguageTag('uk')`.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe if I do that code I get non localized date, like 10-April-2021 18:58:53

Comment: @andrewjames
Excellent! You approach with #locale.forLanguageTag('uk') works!
I tried this:
<td th:text="${#temporals.format(T(java.time.LocalDate).of(#dates.year(tempReport.reportDate),
#dates.month(tempReport.reportDate), #dates.day(tempReport.reportDate)), 'dd-MMMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss', #locale.forLanguageTag('uk'))}"
                th:classappend="${tempReport.status.name}"></td>

and got expected result: 02-жовтня-2021 01:36:35

However, there is another issue: this translation remains always independently on the language switching. Do you happen to know how to resolve this?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean - but if you want to use different languages for different clients, then you can set the locale in the context (rather than hard-coding it into your template). This could be based, for example, on a user's profile/personal settings. There are probably various questions & answers covering this already, I think. If your research does not find a solution, then you can ask a new question. Same goes if I misunderstood the question!

Comment: @andrewjames
I mean that being on ENGLISH locale I have months localized into UKRAINIAN provided that other parts are localized into English as expected: https://prnt.sc/12t6lln
<br/>
Do you think this is another question that might be addressed wthin separate question?

Comment: That looks like a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `#locale.GERMAN` that is just a convenient [constant value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) for one of the more commonly used languages.

You can build a locale for any language using the relevant language tag. So, try `#locale.forLanguageTag('uk')`.

---

**WARNING:**

For BCP 47 language tags (as used by Java's `Locale`), Ukraine (the country) is `UA`, but Ukrainian (the language) is `uk`.

You can combine them into `uk-UA` which is also a valid BCP 47 language tag. This means "the Ukrainian language as used in Ukraine".

That may be redundant, and you may only need `uk`. It's more relevant for languages like French (`fr`) which can be significantly different in France (`FR`) versus Canada (`CA`). So `fr-CA` means "Canadian French". I don't know if there are significant variations of Ukrainian used in other countries, outside of Ukraine.

If you are using the constructor:

```
Locale(String language, String country)
```

then for your purposes, it should be this:

```
Locale('uk', 'UA') // this is correct
```

So, the **WARNING** is this: If you use the following:

```
Locale('uk', 'UK') // this is INCORRECT!
```

then that is ***incorrect*** - it means "the Ukrainian language as used in some unknown location represented by `UK`".

There is an online [validator](https://schneegans.de/lv/?tags=uk-UA%0D%0A&format=text) where you can test these language tags for yourself.

Comment: Thank you! Your approach works well.
It turned to be my misuse of `new java.util.Locale('ua', 'UA')`
instead of `new java.util.Locale('uk', 'UK')`
Never thought UK might stand for Ukraine, not United Kingdom, so
this chunk of code works fine then: 
`<td th:text="${#temporals.format(T(java.time.LocalDate).of(#dates.year(tempReport.reportDate), #dates.month(tempReport.reportDate), #dates.day(tempReport.reportDate)), 'dd-MMMM-yyyy', new java.util.Locale('uk', 'UK'))}"></td>`

Comment: I added a warning to my answer based on your comments. (Also just as a side note, the United Kingdom is `GB` for Great Britain. Switzerland is `CH` for Cantons of Helvetia, or some such... There are some surprises in language and country abbreviations.)